# Power calculation and Ohm's Law for Reactance

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, ohms-law, reactance

Hi I have the following question:

**V = 120V, 
I = 10 A, I lags V by 60degrees**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjBTS6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The load consists of a resistor and an inductor in series.
What is the **reactance** of the inductor?

The way I have tried to solve it:

Since the current lags the voltage 60 degrees:
\$ I = 10 \angle 60 \$

\$V = 120\angle0 V\$

\$V = IZ\$

\$Z = \frac{V}{I}\$ (1)

\$= \frac{120\angle0}{10 \angle 60}\$

\$ = 6-10.4j\$

Hence the reactance \$X_L = -10.4 \$

I know this is wrong, because by convention inductors have positive reactance!
So where am i going wrong?

I could use power formulas for S, P and Q to solve this, but i would like to know why doesn't the above work?
Should I be using the conjugate in (1), it's the only thing I can think of.

Cheers!

Comment: Feels ill posed, with too many variables.

Comment: I have edited it to make it a bit clearer now if that helps. thanks!

Comment: If you expect to figure out the inductance, you need to specify the frequency, and probably the resistance.

Comment: I am only trying to calculate the reactance X_L. You are correct if I was calculating the Inductance.

Comment: If you make voltage the reference at 0°, then to make current -60° because I **lags** V by 60°.  \$ 10 \measuredangle 60 \Omega \$ means leading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i would like to know why doesn't the above work?

It's not \$\angle{60}\$, it's \$\angle{-60}\$ as the denominator: -

[image]

The supply voltage can be regarded as at 0 degrees and the current is lagging 60 degrees behind at 300 degrees. Hence the angle of the current is 300 degrees or -60. See [this](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/phasors.html) website which also shows this picture: -

[image]

Comment: Are you able to explain why we make it -60 degrees when we put it in the denominator?

Comment: No I think I got that wrong so I'm deleting until my brain wakes up.

Comment: OK I think I sorted it.

Comment: Ahh yes, that does make sense when you put it like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In phasor form you get the impedance Z = 20<-60. When you convert it to complex form it will become 20cos(-60)+20sin(-60) j = 10-17.32 j. On complex plane it means 10 units in horizontal and 17.32 units in negative vertical direction.